# how to string numbers to two specific strings

Tags: java

For example, i have a string for first name and for a last name, and then stats from that person. How would i make different stats for another choice of names(string) and have them connected to that specific string(s)?

```
public class project3 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int earnedRuns = 52;
        int inningsPitched = 182;
        double ERA = (earnedRuns * 9.0) / (inningsPitched);
        String FirstName = "Anibal";
        String LastName = "Sanchez";

        System.out.println("Pitcher's first name: " + FirstName);
        System.out.println("Pitcher's last name: " + LastName); 
        System.out.println("Number of earned runs: " + earnedRuns);
        System.out.println("Number of innings pitched: " + inningsPitched);
        System.out.println(FirstName + " " + LastName + " has an ERA of " + ERA);
    }
}
```

Comment: By creating a Player object...?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: Maybe you need a java.util.Map

Comment: I don't know anything about this stuff...my bad. Let's do some physics or something

Comment: @user3316886 Joking aside; start with the tutorials or a good beginner's book on Java. It's not that this isn't a well-asked question, it's just one that is about the most fundamental concept in Java/OOP and answered by basic resources available elsewhere in far more depth than can be provided here.

Comment: I agree, I figured it would be something way more difficult and ahead of me. I was thinking too much about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking into `Object-Oriented Programming`. Google it, you can find a bunch more info on this. You can manage your data as objects, IE instances of classes. See the example below.

```
public class Pitcher {

    private String name;
    //Other data about this pitcher. These are called fields, keep them private.

    //This is a getter, use this to access data from outside the class.
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    //This is a constructor, it will be called when you first create the 
    //class using the 'new' keyword.
    public Pitcher(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public class Project3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Pitcher> pitchers = new ArrayList();
        pitchers.add(new Pitcher("John Doe"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some class which groups all the stats you want to keep track of, for example

```
public class BaseballPlayer {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private int earnedRuns;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Then you would need some sort of Map, to map names or something to that class. So you could do `Map<String, BaseballPlayer> playersMap = new HashMap<String, BaseballPlayer>()` and add your players mapping their full name to the actual BaseballPlayer instance.